# Assessing the fit of a distribution of absolute frequencies to a distribution of relative frequencies

Tags: distributions, frequency

**Problem:** From a related paper, we have a distribution of relative frequencies for a set of actions people do when working with a particular tool. In a study of our own, we measured a set of absolute frequencies for the same actions. We are trying to get a meausre of how well the measured absolute frequencies match the previously reported relative frequencies.

Is there a commonly known method to do this comparison?

We already thought of converting the absolute frequencies to relative ones and taking the mean squared error. However, the mean squared error does not provide us with an absolute measure of how well the absolute frequencies match the relative ones.

**Our Background:** To cut it short: We have enough background to know that we do not know enough. :/ We know common stats methods, but our grasp of the fundamentals is not good enough to be sure about how to adapt existing methods in this case.

Thanks for any pointers on how to approach this!

Comment: A common goodness-of-fit statistic is $\chi^2$. You may want to read about Chi-squared goodness-of-fit -test https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goodness_of_fit#Categorical_data

Comment: Thanks for the pointer! We looked into this earlier and it turned out that Chi-squared methods should not be used with relative frequencies. Would fitting the relative frequencies to the absolute frequencies work if we simply scaled the frequencies to optimizing the mean squared error?

Comment: Are you aware that the chi^2 test of independence is not the same as the chi^2 goodness of fit test? I am not shure how your "fitting relative to absolute" is different from "calculating the expected values" from my link.

Comment: Good point :) Should have seen that earlier... Thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: 1) If the related paper gives also the total (it should), you can reconstruct the absolute frequencies, then you have a contingency table 2) How many groups? Can you plot the frequencies and show us?